# MVC how to call authorized action method from console application

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, console-application

I need to trigger mvc methods from console application, all the methods are under authorize and need login.

after some searching I found this
[How to authenticate in an ASP.NET MVC application from a console application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10036330/how-to-authenticate-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application-from-a-console-application)
which is very similar to my problem,
Someone there mentioned that before calling the wanted method, a login is needed, then using the authentication cookie to send a request to the wanted method.

I'm using forms authentication

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login" timeout="2880" />
</authentication>
```

My code (on console application)

```
  private static void OnTimedEvent(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Get authentication cookie");

        var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://localhost:50709/Account/Login");

        var postData = "UserEmail=Test@gmail.com&Password=P@ssW0rd";
        var data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(postData);

        request.Method = "POST";
        request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        request.ContentLength = data.Length;

        using (var stream = request.GetRequestStream())
        {
            stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
        }



        var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

        var responseString = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();

    }
```

My login action

```
   [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Login(LoginModel model, string returnUrl)
    {
        // Lets first check if the Model is valid or not
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            using (var db = new MarketingLogsEntities())
            {
                bool userValid = db.RegisteredUsers.Any(x => x.UserEmail == model.UserEmail && x.Password == model.Password);



                // User found in the database
                if (userValid)
                {

                    FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(model.UserEmail, false);
                    if (Url.IsLocalUrl(returnUrl) && returnUrl.Length > 1 && returnUrl.StartsWith("/")
                        && !returnUrl.StartsWith("//") && !returnUrl.StartsWith("/\\"))
                    {
                        return Redirect(returnUrl);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    ModelState.AddModelError("", "The user name or password provided is incorrect.");
                }
            }
        }

        return View(model);
    }
```

my response doesn't contain any cookie data inside (cookie returns empty)

[image]

What am I doing wrong?
Appreciate any help.

Comment: First, your ContentLength is "" There for your passing nothing. Second, your Method rsponse is "GET" While you said it is "POST" Check those first.

Comment: Also, double check your Controller for Login, you might have. Validation attribute, which you would have to add a Validation token data to your Form Post.

Comment: contentLength is 4725,
I added my login action,
as for the GET request, I have no idea why its happening, I set => request.Method = "POST";

Comment: You need a single sign on feature.. you need to matain something called machine key in web config btw two applications. Do some digging in single sign on feature